# Calling virtual functions from the constructor and mocking

Tags: c#, mocking, fxcop

Best practice is to not call virtual functions from the constructor of base classes (warning shows up in FxCop or Sonar), however what about classes that are not intended to be used as base classes but have virtual methods for mocking. Is this a case where I should use the GlobalSuppressions file, or is there a way to mock a method that is called in the constructor without it being virtual?

Here is some code to clarify:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        MyVirtualMethod();
    }
    private virtual void MyVirtualMethod() { }
}
```

MyVirtualMethod is virtual for mocking only.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't want to call virtual methods in a constructor is that they won't be called from the constructor of the base class. 
Put another way, if you are instantiating a derived class, you will need to call the derived classes implementation of the virtual method **explicitly** in it's constructor.

So your virtual method will not be virtual.

The following is the example from [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/calling-virtuals-from-ctors.html) trans-coded into C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace VirtualMethodCalledFromConstructor
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Derived d = new Derived();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Base
    {
        public Base()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base::Base()");
            virt();
        }
        public virtual void virt()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base::virt()");
        }
    }

    public class Derived : Base
    {
        public Derived()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived::Derived()");
            virt();
        }

        public virtual void virt()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived::virt()");
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following output in the console:

```
Base::Base()
Base::virt() // <--- not Derived::virt()
Derived::Derived()
Derived::virt()
```

Note that the "Derived::virt()" is only being called because the Derived constructor explicitly called it.

Comment: The idea would be to override virt() in the derived class, however we are not deriving from the class directly. The function is virtual only for mocking purposes. The problem that is being warned about is that it's possible to call a function on a derived class from the base class before the derived classes constructor has run. But since  we're not inheriting anything, it shouldn't be a problem, aka false warning.

Comment: Apparently I am have been making the incorrect assumption about your mocking.  I assumed to you wanted to replace the implementation of a certain method "virt()". If I understand you correctly, you are using a mocking tool that will generate a mock class "Derived" with the same interface as "Base", but which does not actually inherit from "Base".    If this is correct, then I don't understand why your mocking tool requires you to use the 'virtual' keyword. Seems wrong.